# How can I check if a file is empty?

Tags: r

I have thousands of text files and would like to know how to check if a particular file is empty. I am reading all the files using this line of code

```
Y<-grep("*.txt", list.files(), value = TRUE)
```

I would like a list of names of all the blank files. Have to do it in R.

Thanks.

Comment: (Note your regular expression may include files you don't want. Your regular expression searches for any string with `txt` anywhere (except the first char). Cf. `grep("*.txt", c("file.txt", "filewithtxt.doc", "txtfile.docx"))`. As Konrad mentioned, the proper regex is `\\.txt$`.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`file.size`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.info.html):

```
empty = filenames[file.size(filenames) == 0L]
```

`file.size` is a shortcut for [`file.info`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.info.html):

```
info = file.info(filenames)
empty = rownames(info[info$size == 0L, ])
```

Incidentally, there’s a better way of listing text files than using `grep`: specify the `pattern` argument to `list.files`:

```
list.files(pattern = '\\.txt$')
```

Note that the pattern needs to be a regular expression, not a glob — and the same is true for `grep`!

Comment: Thank you. Can I simply put filenames=Y or do I have put it in a loop?

Comment: No loop necessary. In fact, try not to use loops in R at all, R is designed so that they are (almost completely) unnecessary.

Comment: Very nice. It is possible to do it in one line when conditionals is need. I have some data where noises are not always present. So in order to process it when data is there I have following code: `if (file.info('FILENAME')$size == 0) { <<do your job>> }`

Comment: If there are some files are empty and some don't, and I need to put in an if statement. I need to adjust to `if (nrow(info [info$size==0,]) !=0)`, because it will throw error when the table is empty using rownames

Comment: Since R 3.2 `file.size()` allows you to save some typing.

Comment: `file.size()` does not work with quasi empty files, e. g. created like this.
`write.table(x = "", file = "my_file.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, append = FALSE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")`

Comment: @aGricolaMZ No, it works just fine. What makes you think otherwise? The file you’ve created *isn’t* empty. If you create an actually empty file (by whatever way), `file.size` will correctly return `0`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I've found that for `file.size(write.table("", "my_file.csv"))` is 3, however if I use `NULL` it works fine: `file.size(write.table(NULL, "my_file.csv"))` is 0.

Comment: @aGricolaMZ Yes, because `write.table("", "my_file.cscv")` does *not* create an empty file. Just open the file in an editor (or whatever): you’ll see that it isn’t empty.

Answer (score 4):

For a functional approach, you might first write a predicate:

```
file.empty <- function(filenames) file.info(filenames)$size == 0
```

And then filter the list of files using it:

```
Filter(file.empty, dir())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to check if a file in the system is empty or not before uploading it.

```
my_file<-readLines(paste0("<path of file/file name.extension>"))
my_file=="" #TRUE - means the file is empty
```

Answer (score -2):

```
find . -empty
```

or

```
find . -empty |awk -F\/ '{print $FN}'
```

If you want to limit just txt files:

```
find . -empty -name "*.txt"
```

If you want only asci files (not just .txt)

```
find . -empty -type f
```

put it all together:

```
find . -empty -type f -name "*.txt" |awk -F\/ '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Notice that this solution isn’t platform independent.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with 'R'!